# Unity Instantiate object at mouse point getting wrong coordinates

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, raycasting

I 'm working on an RTS and want to place a gameobject on the mouseposition. This works, but the object is placed in the wrong location.

The picture below shows a raycast of where my mouse is. But the object (cube, bottom left of the terrain) gets instantiated nowhere near the raycast.

[image: raycast]

This is the code i'm using to get the position, what am I doing wrong?

`toBuild.build(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(hit.point));`

Comment: Could you post more of your code please? Why are you using `ScreenToWorldPoint`? You seem to use a raycast which already gives a result in world space ..

Comment: If I use the point from the raycast it gets instantiated closer to the mouse position but still not correct.

The actual instantiation is done through:
```Instantiate(this, location, Quaternion.identity)```

This being the gameobject, and location is the location from the raycast

Comment: Well so ... Can you show your complete code of the raycast etc?

Comment: Yes of course here it is, it seperated in different classes but here's the callstack:


    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 500, Color.blue);
    ...
    Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 500);
    ...
    toBuild.build(hit.point);
    ...
    Transform transform = Instantiate(this, location, 
    Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<Transform>();
 

That's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found the reason why the position was incorrect. I had placed a box collider around the terrain and the raycast was hitting that apparently. I removed the box collider and it worked fine.

Comment: Going to accept this as the answer, hopefully someone will find some use out of this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that you are raycasting in world space but for some reason, you use the cast hit as a screen position. It should already be in a world position so don't use Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint().

Comment: Thanks for your reply Daniel. If I just use the coordinates from the raycast, it gets instantiated closer to my mouse but still not quite where my mouse is.

Comment: How do you make the raycast?

Comment: ```
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 500, Color.blue);
    ...
    Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 500);
    ...
    toBuild.build(hit.point);
    ...
    Transform transform = Instantiate(this, location, 
    Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<Transform>();
 
```